# How to fix : Install a driver providing OpenGL 2.0 or higher

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, opengl

First things first, I'm using Windows 7 with 32 bit.

When I open a software there is an error saying `Install a driver providing OpenGL 2.0 or higher`, There are many software which shows the same problem.

I know that I've to update my graphics drivers in order to eradicate this problem. I have an Intel Graphics card, but whenever I look for an update from `Intel Driver and Support Assistant`, it shows that all of my drivers are up-to-date. When I look at `OpenGL Extensions Viewer 5.0.5`, it shows that the version of `OpenGL` is 1.4.

Yes, I know that there are other questions also like this, however, my problem is a little bit different. From other questions, I got that I've to update my graphics drivers, But however, my all drivers are up-to-date according to `Intel Driver and Support Assistant`.

So, now what I've to do in order to fix this error.

Do I need to buy a new Graphics Card, or this problem can be fixed without buying a new one?

If I've to buy a new Graphics Card, then which one? I don't know about Graphics Card anything.

Note: I'm not that much in gaming. I just want to edit my videos.

[image]
[image]

Comment: OpenGL support requires hardware support does your hardware support OpenGL 2.0+. Edit your question to include which versions of OpenGL it supports.

Comment: @HarshitSeksaria No; That’s the default version your hardware supports, without any drivers installed, that isn’t what I asked.

Comment: @HarshitSeksaria - Provide details on the hardware you have, specifically, indicate what GPU you have.  If you are using the iGPU within your Intel processor, you need to edit your question, to indicate that is the case.  Since you already accepted an answer, which is actually an incorrect answer, I will simply contact a moderator to clean up the comment section.  Worth pointing out, the Dual-Core CPU E5300, doesn't even have an iGPU.  **So it is unclear the reason you are attempting to install an Intel display driver.**

Comment: @HarshitSeksaria - Just because you accepted an answer does not mean that answer is accurate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Judging from the model, age, CPU, etc.  I believe you have a [Lenovo ThinkCentre M58e](https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-thinkcentre-m58-intel-174-pentium-174-dual-core-e5300-2-6ghz-250gb-hdd-series/specs/).   Your problem is less the type of slot in the machine (it has both classic PCI and PCI-E according to its detail sheet) but the physical size.  You will need a low-profile video card.  The two upgrades listed for the unit are:

> ATI HD3470 GDDR3 256MB LP - VGA+DP
>
> nVidia G100 DDR2 256MB LP - DVI-I (With DVI-I to VGA Dongle)

You can use a newer card than these, and would want to for what you want to do, but I still recommend a new machine, especially with your motherboard returning weird and invalid values in diagnostics. Further, you will need a better power supply than the one provided for the newest cards that are worth having.

Comment: [That adapter only supports OpenGL 1.4](https://www.intel.com/assets/pdf/prodbrief/317311.pdf).  You will need a new graphics adapter.

Comment: @CDove - You should update your answer and remove any information that does not apply to the author.  It is extremely busy, and there are several statements, that do not even apply to the author.  You don't need to include "edit" statements, we have a revision, we know edits have been made.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt provide the model of your graphics card, which would provide a 100% certain answer.  However, based on your information, the answer is most likely that your GPU does not support OpenGL 2.0.  The version of OpenGL is based on hardware, not software.  This is why you are limited to an older driver.  You will need to upgrade to a newer graphics card to get OpenGL 2 or higher.

Comment: @HarshitSeksaria thats entirely up to you and your budget.  search an online store such as Amazon for graphics cards.  The OpenGL version will be listed in the description.  Also, OpenGL 2 is a very old standard, so any modern graphics card will support a much higher version, usually around version 4 or higher.  You do not need to buy the latest or most expensive card just to get OpenGL 2 or higher.